# Get menu bar command from Foxpro application or call the command of a menu by using its menu reference definition

Tags: menu, popup, foxpro

I need to replicate a sysmenu on Foxpro to a popup menu, but I can´t find a way to programmatically get the commands of the bars in the menu. If I could call this commands by using only the menu id, it would solve my problem. I'm looping through the menu with `CNTBAR()` and `CNTPAD()`, using `GETBAR()` `GETPAD()` to get the names and replicate to a popup. But if a bar or menu has a command assigned to it, I can't get its content or call it by using the path to the menu. What is the best way to replicate the commands of the menu to the popup in Foxpro?

Comment: If it's a built-in menu item, check out SYS(1500). If custom, consider having the menu and the other place call the same outside routine.

Comment: Thanks, it does work with sys(1500) @TamarE.Granor